# Disable the FN key on Microsoft media keyboard

Tags: wireless-keyboard, fn-key

I have a Microsoft all-in-one media keyboard. Is there any way to lock/remove/disable the FN key?

[image: Keyboard]

Comment: Have you tried fn+numlock? (may be temporary/per-login)

Comment: @bertieb i dont have numlock.. added an image.

Comment: Software won’t help because it’s a hardware “problem”.

Comment: Perhaps this could be off help https://gist.github.com/tehshane/8765405

Comment: try pressing CAPS LOCK 2 or 3 times, it toggles the fn function

Comment: If somebody ends up here with the version of the keyboard that don't have the FN lock feature I think I found a solution. I shared it on the 4th page of a MS related forum (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-tms/microsoft-all-in-one-keyboard-shortcut-keys-fn/92175afb-8505-4ac8-89be-f48d1b205e06). Short answer is: open the keyboard and find a way to permanently block the FN key.

Answer (score 41):

Try pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to disable the fn-lock, see this [Microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-do-i-use-the-fn-key-f-lock-key-alternate-command-keys-fccfaf23-38f0-88a8-9b44-a18f24523b79) for more information:

> Enabling FN Lock on the All in One Media Keyboard
>
> To enable FN Lock on the All in One Media Keyboard, press the FN key, and the Caps Lock key at the same time. To disable FN Lock, press the FN key, and the Caps Lock key at the same time again.

Comment: Do you have a reference link for your answer?

Comment: **Important**: Apparently not all MS All-in-One media keyboards are the same. This works on **most** of them, but it has no effect on others. If you follow this MS Answers thread all the way through, you'll see a number of people who are not able to use this keyboard combo (and add my keyboard to the list). http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-tms/microsoft-all-in-one-keyboard-shortcut-keys-fn/92175afb-8505-4ac8-89be-f48d1b205e06 I'm still investigating whether perhaps you need at least a certain minimum version of Mouse and Keyboard Center for the fix to work.

Comment: Amesome, that even worked in Linux! (So, a hardware solution.) I wish this worked for the Logitech T400 as well (but no such luck).

Comment: For me it works only until keyboard is turned off. Is there a way to keep that settings permanently?

Comment: I have two Microsoft All-in-One keyboards, which I supposed to be identical. Turns out this Fn+Caps trick works for only one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Try long pressing the function key...It worked for me with my Microsoft designer keyboard. The light on the Fn key turns on....